# Git push not send changes to remote git repository in a subdomain

Tags: git

I have a remote Git repository for my website, for example www.website.com which also has a few subdomains. The main directory of the whole project is www.website.com and the subdomains are inside that main directory, for example, for the subdomain english, the path of the subdomain is www.website.com/english/

The problem is that the new changes that I push are reflected only in the main domain and not on the subdomains. So, if I make changes for the www.website.com, commit and push, I can see those changes online, but if I change any file in the english directory, commit and push, the changes are not shown online (does not matter if I open english.website.com or www.website.com/english/).

Also, I forgot to add, when i try the command git push after making new changes, i don't get an error and if I try again, I get already up-to-date.

How do I fix this? Do I need multiple repos for each subdomain?

Thank you

Comment: Did you get any conflict on `git pull` on server?

Comment: @jagad89 I am not sure I understand. I can not git pull on the server and if I try to pull locally, I get no errors, just that it's already up-to-date.